# Wordpress not encoding "é"

Tags: plugins

i have some problem encoding. I m making a plugin and in my table i have insert some words with the "é' but the result of display is �.

My tables are utf8_general_ci, in wp config the encoding is utf8. I tried also to comment define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );

But nothing is working. How can i do?

This is the request

```
global $wpdb;   
$resu = $wpdb->get_results('
SELECT '.$wpdb->prefix.'mic_combinaisons.id, '.$wpdb->prefix.'mic_keyword.keyword, '.$wpdb->prefix.'mic_secteurs.libelle
FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'mic_combinaisons
INNER JOIN '.$wpdb->prefix.'mic_keyword ON '.$wpdb->prefix.'mic_keyword.id = '.$wpdb->prefix.'mic_combinaisons.id_keyword
INNER JOIN '.$wpdb->prefix.'mic_secteurs ON '.$wpdb->prefix.'mic_secteurs.id_secteurs = '.$wpdb->prefix.'mic_combinaisons.id_secteur', OBJECT 
);
```

and i try to display like

```
foreach ( $resu as $res ) {
    $id = $res->id;
    $keyword = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$res->keyword));
    $secteur = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-",$res->libelle));
    $mic_slug = normalize($keyword) ."-".normalize($secteur)."-k".$id;
    echo($mic_slug);
```

Comment: What’s your code saving and displaying the data?

Comment: I did a request that show the values of the table. In SQL the words is show correctly but in wordpress there is always this �

Comment: You’re putting the values through the built in PHP functions strtolower and normalize. Have you done anything to test if these are responsible?

Comment: I ve testing also without this functions. I ve create this function for try to fix the problem but nothing, the result is the same

Comment: Setting the charset and collation after the table has already been created won't make WP go back and change the tables. Also have you tried the multibyte versiions of the string functions? E.g. `mb_strtolower`?